# How to use getelementByID in Javascript when ID values are in loop and auto incrementing

Tags: php, javascript, variables, getelementbyid

I have a table being pulled from MySql through PHP.. The TD in the tables have unique IDs and get autoincremented in a loop.

```
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

  {     $i = $i+1;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['DRAINNAME'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td id='lat" . $i ."'>" . $row['LATITUDE'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td id='lon" . $i ."'>" . $row['LONGITUDE'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> <input type='button' onclick='detect_load();' value='Click Me' /><br>
        <div id='divsec". $i ."' style='width: 200px; height: 200px;'></div> </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Im writing a Javascript function which should get values from the unique IDs of the TDs..

```
  function getLocation(pos) {
      latitude = document.getElementById('lat'+ '<?php echo $i; ?>').innerHTML;
      longitude = document.getElementById('lon'+ '<?php echo $i; ?>').innerHTML;
      load_map();
  }
```

But the  `'<?php echo $i; ?>'` dosent seem to work.. :(
I mean, for example--- If the value of i is 2, then td becomes lat2 and lon2 
but in javascript, its not taking those ID values i.e. lat2 and lon2..
its giving an error saying its NULL ..

Here is the full Code if you cannot understand it....

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var latitude = '';
  var longitude = '';

  function getLocation(pos) {
      latitude = document.getElementById('lat'+ <?php echo $i; ?>).innerHTML;
      longitude = document.getElementById('lon'+ <?php echo $i; ?>).innerHTML;
      load_map();
  }
  function unknownLocation(){alert('Could not find location');}


  function detect_load(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation, unknownLocation);

  }

  function load_map() { 
    if(latitude == '' || longitude == '')
      return false;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var config = {
      zoom: 11,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('divsec'+ <?php echo $i; ?>),config);

                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: latlng, 
                  map: map, 
                  title:"Your requested location!"
              });

  }
</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php
include 'datalogin.php';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT DRAINNAME, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM draininfo");

echo "<table border='1' name='tab1'>
<tr>
<th>Drain Name</th>
<th>Latitude</th>
<th>Longitude</th>
<th>Show On Map</th>
</tr>";
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

  {     $i = $i+1;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['DRAINNAME'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td id='lat" . $i ."'>" . $row['LATITUDE'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td id='lon" . $i ."'>" . $row['LONGITUDE'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> <input type='button' onclick='detect_load();' value='Click Me' /><br>
        <div id='divsec". $i ."' style='width: 200px; height: 200px;'></div> </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work"? Please be more specific in your error.

Comment: Not sure why you are not passing i into the javascript function as a parameter. You may want to clarify about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you creating the getLocation dynamically on the server side when you generate the table or are you trying to use the PHP variables on the client side? You won't be able to directly use server side variables on the client side as they don't know about each other. You need to use some middle man (ie Ajax) to communicate between the two locations. Imagine your PHP is in Building A and your JS is in Building B to communicate you need a runner to run back and forth because building A doesn't have any phone lines to talk to building b and vice versa.

Comment: Where is the $i coming from, is the javascript function being defined inside the original PHP loop, if not the $i will be null?

Comment: what is pos parametr means. Need you get 'lat'+pos ?

Comment: Where is the getLocation called from?  Is it an onclick event for something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woah, the last question contained a little bit more context.

I would not retrieve the information via DOM. It's better to supply this information directly to the function:

```php
echo "<td id='lat" . $i ."'>" . $row['LATITUDE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td id='lon" . $i ."'>" . $row['LONGITUDE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td> <input type='button' onclick='detect_load(" 
    . $row['LATITUDE'] . ","
    . $row['LONGITUDE'] . "," 
    . "\"divsec" . $i . "\");' value='Click Me' /><br>
<div id='divsec". $i ."' style='width: 200px; height: 200px;'></div> </td>";
```

And then the Javascript-part - **incomplete** - but notice how the parameters are passed through to the point where they are needed:

```javascript
function createGetLocation(latitude, longitude, div) {
    return function(pos) {
        load_map(latitude, longitude, div);
    };
}

function unknownLocation(){alert('Could not find location');}


function detect_load(latitude, longitude, div) {
    var getLocation = createGetLocation(latitude, longitude, div);
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation, unknownLocation);
}

function load_map(latitude, longitude, div) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var config = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(div), config
    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: You are my man .. !!
The script worked .. :D:D:D:D:D
Billion thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery

```
for (elem : $("#table-id #tr-id td")){
   $(elem) // you can access your td object here if you have an organized td sequence in each tr
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the PHP script and Javascript file are two different things, the variable `$i` does not carry over.

I'm not exactly sure where you call getLocation from, but I am guessing that pos is the numbered element?  If so, then do:

```
latitude = document.getElementById('lat' + pos).innerHTML;
longitude = document.getElementByid('lon' + pos).innerHTML;
load_map();
```

If this does not answer your question, please update your question to give us a little more information about where these functions are being called (more specifically, the getLocation function).

Comment: Okay.  Now I understand a little more.  The problem with your code, and I'm trying to think of exactly what you are trying to do, is that the pos variable already contains position information for the current position.  Because getLocation was called by the getCurrentPosition function, pos is an object.  You can get lat/lon by doing pos.coords.latitude and pos.coords.longitude.  Probably what vstm posted is what you are looking for.